# Issue with timer countdown jQuery php

Tags: php, jquery, timer, countdown

I need help with the code below. The page timer does not count down correctly, it counts 2 seconds at a time.

This is for a MMORPG game, the page in particular is crimes. The timer is supposed to countdown in line with the database but as I say it is counting 2 seconds at a time.

I'm not sure what part of the code is incorrect, any tips? All help would be greatly appreciated if anyone can.

Thanks

```
<?
    $wait8 = (time() + 1800);
    $timeleft8 = ($time8 - time());
    $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' LIMIT 1");
    $arr = mysql_fetch_array($get);
    $time8 = $arr['crimetime8'];
    $timeleft8 = ($time8 - time()) ; 
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $(".countdown").each(function() {
                val = $(this).html();
                if ((val - 1) >= 0 && !(isNaN(val))) {
                    val = parseInt(val) - 1;
                    $(this).html(val);
                } else {
                    $(this).html("<font color='green'><b>Available</b></font>");
                }
            });
        }, 10000);
    });
</script>

<span class='countdown'>{$timeleft1}</span>

<? } ?>
```